# restart openerp 7 server on Xubuntu

Tags: service, odoo, updates, restart

I am coding a custom module on Oerp7 on Xubuntu 12.04, and today, suddently (after some moduifications in the code I think), the restart server command still do not affecting my module.
i restart with this command :

> sudo /etc/init.d/openerp-server restart

but the compiled (.pyc) files stayed unchange.
If I delete the module in the addons dir, the module don't properly work giving me a message saying that models are absent. that is normal; but why restart don't change anything. even if I modify the **init**.py or **openerp**.py files.

According tome is as restarting by this command now make nothing, while yesterday it did.
So, please, how could I fix that now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `-u modulename` in the command line that starts the OpenERP server.  So either modify the `/etc/init.d/openerp-server` script to have it there, or just start the server manually while you are developing.

Comment: You need -u only when changes to the database should be made - as new fields in the model or modified xml view etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openerp-server stop
ps aux | grep openerp
```

to see if the server really stopped.

Start the server with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openerp-server start
```

Look also in the logs (/var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log for ex.) to see what heppens.